# Oracle NULL value also filtering

Tags: oracle

Im trying to filter the category 'Student'. But NULL category also filtering out. Could you please let me know how to filter only Student not NULL value.

```
Query:

select * from customer where category != 'Student'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null isn't comporable with anything, even itself. To include it you need to have a separate condition for it:

```
select * from customer where category is null or category != 'Student'
```

You could also `nvl` or `coalesce` the column to a magic value, but explicitly looking for null is cleaner, I find.

[Quick SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4cc84/1).